# How I can move navbar onto img?

Tags: html, css

I need to move navbar onto image. I've tried to set `position: absolute;` for navbar but it collapsed. How can I do this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.global-padding {
  padding: 0 98px;
}

.container {
  width: 1172px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.order-us-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 212px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3.6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #212121;
  border-radius: 23px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.35);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 63px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar_fixed {
  /* pass */
}

.navbar__logo-img {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -moz-user-drag: none;
  -o-user-drag: none;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar__menu-link {
  padding: 10px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar__menu-link_active {
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  color: #212121;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar__search {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.navbar__search-icon {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -moz-user-drag: none;
  -o-user-drag: none;
}

.slider__background-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider__text {
  position: absolute;
}

.slider__status-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.status-text_trending {
  color: #43a047;
}

.slider__h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 62px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 72px;
}

.slider__content {
  width: 450px;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.slider__circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #c7c7c7;
}

.slider__circle_active {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <nav class="navbar global-padding">
    <a href="#" class="navbar__logo-link">LOGO</a>
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
      <li class="navbar__menu-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__menu-link navbar__menu-link_active">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="navbar__menu-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__menu-link">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li class="navbar__menu-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__menu-link">HISTORY</a></li>
      <li class="navbar__menu-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__menu-link">SHOWROOM</a></li>
      <li class="navbar__menu-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__menu-link">CONTACT</a></li>
      <button class="navbar__search"><img class="navbar__search-icon" src="{% static 'img/search.svg' %}" alt="Search"></button>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1350789/pexels-photo-1350789.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=two-assorted-color-padded-chairs-near-side-table-1350789.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Slider image" class="slider__background-image">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want an image in the nav bar?

Comment: No. I want navbar on ```.slider__background-image```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather set `img` to `position: absolute` instead of `navbar`. Keep in mind you'd need `img`'s parent container to be set to `position: relative`.

**Edit 1**-
You might also need to set `z-index` for `img` if it blocks `navbar` from appearing.

**Edit 2**-
For the `navbar` going out of screen issue-

1. Use `width: 100vw` for `nav` element
2. Set `flex-grow: .5` and `flex-basis: 50%` to `ul` in the `nav` element

*Note-* You can adjust the amount of `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` to whatever you want.

Comment: It works almost how I want. But my navbar got collapsed. http://prntscr.com/t3pwnt

Comment: it seems to be working fine. what's the exact issue.please provide a reproducible link.

Comment: Missing distance between logo and menu. How it must looks: http://prntscr.com/t3q3jq. How it looks: http://prntscr.com/t3q46k

Comment: the issue was the `width` of navbar getting shrunk. setting `width: 100vw` fixes it. I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Your code have some serious problems which indicates lack of experience, and they are as follows-

1- why you want to specify image differently and position it onto navbar? Instead you can  use `background-image: url('');` property with the parent container and your desired result will be achieved.

2- If you want gap between logo and image then don't specify it with a particular margin. Kindly use `float:right;` for links and `float: left;` for your logo, then you can specify margins to any specific link just as you want it to be.

3- Kindly make us clear about your actual query and share the snippet of essential information only!

you should first make your code clear and up to the point, and then kindly specify your queries in details.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want an image in navbar?**

add width="50px";

```
<img  width="50px" alt="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can set the Image as css Background image

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: red;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1350789/pexels-photo-1350789.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=two-assorted-color-padded-chairs-near-side-table-1350789.jpg&fm=jpg);
  height: 50vw;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: .5rem;
}
.nav-container a{margin: 0 .3rem; color: red}
```

```html
<nav><h3>Company</h3><div class="nav-container"><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">History</a><a href="#">Pricing</a><div></nav>
```

Comment: I could, but Django doesn't support references to static files in css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button class="navbar__search" style="background-image: url('your_image.jpg');">Search</button>
```

in your_image specify the image you wish to be displayed.

remove img tag and check it.

Comment: ```.navbar``` must be on ```.slider__background-image```. My question isn't about it.